# Editable <td> filed using jQuery and AJAX, limit count and allow numbers only

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

The following is an inline insert using HTML5 table data to a database table using jQuery and AJAX. I would like to limit the fields only with number and limit count. These are not text input fields.

For example all fields should only be able to input numbers. and Number field allows numbers up-to 2 digit all other fields allows numbers up-to 3 digits.

how can I do this this ?

```js
$("#btnSaveAction").on("click", function() {
  params = ""
  $("td[contentEditable='true']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "") {
      if (params != "") {
        params += "&";
      }
      params += $(this).data('id') + "=" + $(this).text();
    }
  });
  if (params != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "insert-row.html",
      type: "POST",
      data: params,
      success: function(response) {
        $("#ajax-response").append(response);
        $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="add-product">
  <div class="txt-heading">Add Product</div>
  <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th><strong>Number</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Count</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Code</strong></th>
        <th style="text-align:right;"><strong>Price</strong></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        < <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_number"></td>
          <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_count"></td>
          <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_code"></td>
          <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_price" style="text-align:right;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="btnSaveAction">Save to Database</div>
</div>
```

code is from [here](https://phppot.com/jquery/inline-insert-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: You don't have any input fields. Please scratch that "tutorial" that you found and linked, it is horrible and wrong. Find a normal tutorial that explains you how to use input fields and read their values before submitting.

Comment: Please clarify `"For example all fields should only be able to input numbers. and Number field allows numbers up-to 2 digit all other fields allows numbers up-to 3 digits."` - there are no specific `Number fields` so which are to be treated as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an event listener to your `td[contentEditable="true"]`s and check the pressed key and the length of the text. Then just call `e.preventDefault()` to deny the edit whenever the key is not allowed or it would put the length beyond the limit. Below I used the `"keydown"` event as it fires before the keypress is complete and before the character is added to the element.

```js
$('td[contentEditable="true"]').on("keydown", e => {
  // define allowed keys
  const allow = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', 'Tab', 'Backspace']
  // get pressed key
  const k = e.key
  if (allow.includes(k)) {
    // get the value before this keydown
    const val = e.target.textContent

    // determine the limit according to your logic
    const limit = Number(e.target.dataset['length']);

    if (val.length == limit && 'Tab' != k && 'Backspace' != k) {
      // pressing this key would put the value over the limit
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('deny: ' + k, val, limit)
    } else
      console.log('allow: ' + k, val, limit)

  } else {
    // key not allowed
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('deny: ' + k)
  }

})
$("#btnSaveAction").on("click", function() {
  params = ""
  $("td[contentEditable='true']").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != "") {
      if (params != "") {
        params += "&";
      }
      params += $(this).data('id') + "=" + $(this).text();
    }
  });
  if (params != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "insert-row.html",
      type: "POST",
      data: params,
      success: function(response) {
        $("#ajax-response").append(response);
        $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div id="add-product">
  <div class="txt-heading">Add Product</div>
  <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th><strong>Number</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Count</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Code</strong></th>
        <th style="text-align:right;"><strong>Price</strong></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_number" data-length="2"></td>
        <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_count" data-length="2"></td>
        <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_code" data-length="2"></td>
        <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_price" data-length="3" style="text-align:right;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="btnSaveAction">Save to Database</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works, but first field is allowing 2 digit numbers and second is 3 digit. what if there are more fields and digits/counts need more control ? is there a way to mark number fields like field 1 = 2, field 2 = 3 etc.. so that field 1 will allow 2 digit numbers and field 2 will allow 3 digit numbers. and if field 3 = 10, it should allow 10 digit numbers.

Comment: It was unclear what your intent was that's why I put the comment "determine the limit according to your logic" You can just use another data attribute, see my updated answer.